# Backbone.js collector data missing

Tags: json, backbone.js, drupal-7, drupal-views

I have this simple [JSON](http://dev-sw-budget.gotpantheon.com/sort-coordinator-json) feed which I am attempting to read in a BackBone.JS app.

My challenge is the network traffic comes up completely blank as illustrated below:

[image]
Using the following code:

```
 //Collections
  var Topics = Backbone.Collection.extend({
      model: TopicStruct,

      initialize: function(){
          console.log('Collector Responding!');
      },

      url: 'http://dev-sw-budget.gotpantheon.com/sort-coordinator-json',

      render: function(){
          console.log('Topics Render Responding!');
      },

  });
```

Why am I not getting my data in my Backbone app?

UPDATE:

My fetching code:

```
$(document).ready(
      function(){
          console.log('--- DOM Ready!');
          var topics = new Topics();
          var topicsView = new TopicsList({collection: topics});
          topics.fetch({reset: true});

          $('#data table').append(topicsView.el);
      }
  );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem it's that you are not calling `fetch()` in your collection. I have put your code together in a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Puigcerber/CJ5yx/7/) and it works.

```
var topics = new Topics();
topics.fetch();
```

Comment: Thanks for you input but I was calling fetch. I have included a code fragment in an update to my question. I've tried a number of JSON feeds but fields continue to be ignored and not fetched by the browser

Comment: Have you checked the example in the JsFiddle? If you open the console you can see it working.

Comment: Thanks again. I have looked at the JSFiddle and you are right - it does work. However, the network traffic shows one field out of two is begin fetched. The JSON feed contains NID and AUTHOR fields. Only the NID is being fetched by the browser

Comment: Are you sure? Because http://dev-sw-budget.gotpantheon.com/sort-coordinator-json has just the `nid`field.

Comment: Yep! Perhaps your browser is showing you a cached version. The link you provided shows two fields per json object

Comment: What do you mean? If I go to http://dev-sw-budget.gotpantheon.com/sort-coordinator-json that it's the link that appears in your code, it loads an array with 17 objects whose only field is nid.

Comment: Checkout the update I just included in you answer above

Comment: Weird, I just see the `nid` fields, but anyway, if Backbone it's able to fetch the collection both fields should be inside of the models.

Comment: I agree but that is the nature of the problem I'm facing. The network data shows lots of JSON fields have been dropes

Comment: Don't you think then that the problem is in your backend? Whoever is serving that `sort-coordinator-json` is failing to serve all the data.

Comment: No, I'm serving the JSON from a different Drupal based site. I'm using Views to generate the JSON. I'm just surprised we seem to be seeing different data. Regardless, I have two separate Views generating JSON from the same site and my BackBone.js app still doesn't see all the fields.

Comment: Thanks for your continued help. I just created a link within my Backbone app which points to sort-coordinator-json. Just as you are experiencing, I'm seeing single field data instead of two. I literally have two chrome windows open side-by-side pointing at the same address but the page loaded from the backbone app shows only NID data while the page I load directly shows both NID & AUTHOR ???

Comment: Weirdest thing ever. May be you experiencing cache problems?

Comment: I feel like an idiot. The problem is PERMISSIONS! The window where I go directly to the JSON feed shows all the fields because I am logged in. The link from the Backbone app shows just the NID because there is a permission set to disallow anonymous users to view the value of AUTHOR. I am really sorry for wasting your time.